# Windows 7 screen goes blank after logging in

Tags: windows-7, windows, black-screen-of-death

Whenever I login to windows 7, the screen goes black. I used ctrl+win+del to end explorer.exe then start new task 'explorer.exe' again. This made the screen come back but the problem persists when I restart my computer. I don't want to repeat this process every time... Please help me, to troubleshoot this problem. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Do you have a second monitor attached to the PC? Is that monitor really a TV? If so, I'm guessing that what is really happening is that your video card is selecting that as your primary display. If you remove that device and reboot it should all be OK (except that you won't have your TV connected anymore).

Answer (score -1):

I have an HP EliteBook that did the same thing, and I noticed after trial and error that the problem was with the WiFi adapter. When I logged in with the WiFi adapter disabled it loaded windows just find. I have since updated the WiFi drivers and it works fine either way now.

I would recommend examining you device drivers with the manufactures website and making sure that they are all up to date.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to troubleshoot this problem, you can first try Safe Mode. To enter the Safe Mode, press `F8` on computer start-up before the Windows logo appears, and follow the instructions on the screen.

If your desktop load with no problem in Safe Mode, that's probably some hardware or auto-start software that is causing the problem. If it doesn't even load the desktop in Safe Mode I would say I have no idea where the problem is.

If the desktop works fine in Safe Mode, you can try to restart back to your normal desktop and try disabling all auto-start programs. This can be done with `msconfig` usually. This page: http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/msconfig_win7.html shows you how to use `msconfig` to configure auto-start programs. Simply uncheck everything that auto-starts and see if your desktop load at next boot. If that doesn't help it's probably a hardware/driver issue as is mentioned by other users.

If it does help, you can do **binary search** on those auto-start programs to identify the one causing this problem.

---

If you cannot find the problem, for example, you desktop doesn't load in Safe Mode, or it doesn't show up even if you have unchecked all auto-start programs and disconnected all additional hardware... I would say, it always solve the problem to reinstall your operating system (Windows).

If you don't want to reinstall and don't mind not to solve this problem elegantly, you can probably add `explorer` as an auto-start.